# How to write a base class for DRY in this situation without DI in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, jvm, refactoring, dry

I got 2 cases for a class, one is like this:

```
class User {
    private val name:Name = NameGenerator()

    fun sayName() {
        println(this.name.fakeName)
    }
}
```

The other one is:

```
class User(suggestion:String) {
    private val name:Name = NameGenerator(suggestion)

    fun sayName() {
        println(this.name.fakeName)
    }
}
```

Now you see the differences, it's all about that `name`, it has 2 different ways to initialize.

How could I write a base class to DRY in this case?

I end up with something like this:

```
abstract class BaseUser {
    protected val name:Name = MockName()

    fun sayName() {
        println(this.name.fakeName)
    }
}
```

Then I can use it like:

```
class UserCaseOne():BaseUser() {

}

class UserCaseTwo(suggestion:String):BaseUser() {
    init {
        this.name = NameGenerator(suggestion)
    }
}
```

This is pretty lame considering that I have to use a mock object to initialize.

Are there better ways to do this? Without injecting the implementation? I don't want to force the `UserCaseTwo` to have a redundant constructor.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is essentially two combine your first two `User` classes into a single class, you could do this:

```
class User(suggestion: String? = null) {
    private val name: NameGenerator = suggestion?.let { NameGenerator(it) } ?: NameGenerator()

    fun sayName() {
        println(this.name.fakeName)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I think I can't do this. Because the example is a little bit simple while in the real code, caseOne and caseTwo will be in 2 jar file where the `suggestion` is a class and can't be appeared in the caseOne jar file.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be acceptable to make the name provisioning part of the constructor signature by taking a function as a parameter? The following approach enables the desired abstraction imho:

```
class User(private val nameProvider: () -> Name) {
    private val name: Name by lazy(nameProvider)

    fun sayName() {
        println(this.name.fakeName)
    }
}
```

You can create `User`s with any `nameProvider` such as:

```
User { MockName() }
User { NameGenerator("blah") }
```